# Spring <mvc:annotation-driven /> and <mvc:resources can't use together?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, freemarker

My application's folder structure is as follows.

```
web/WEB-INF/templates/
    -home.ftl

web/resources/css/Home_files
    -test.css
```

When using both `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/Home_files" />`  tags it couldn't resolve view (http://localhost:8080/info/home/index.html).

- without `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/Home_files" />`  tag view is resolved but images ans css couldn't resolve.
- without `<mvc:annotation-driven />`  tag view could not be resolved but images and css could be resolved.

How do i load both view and static content together?

here is my config xml files and homeController.

## info-servlet.xml (configuration file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        ">

<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/templates/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web.controllers"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/Home_files" />

</beans>
```

## controller

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/home")

public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index.html")

    public String getHome(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {

        return "home";

    }

}
```

## web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/info-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>info</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/info-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- The mapping for the default servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>info</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that path is not correct in `<mvc:resources>` tag. Add a forward slash (/) at the end of location.

Instead of

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/Home_files" />
```

Use this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/Home_files/" />
```